# What is the best way to represent a chart of distribution of time intervals in Datadog?

Tags: charts, statistics, datadog, statsd

I have a server that processes packets from different devices. Devices can report in different intervals.
I would like to make a chart showing the distribution of intervals by the count of devices (how many devices are reporting within 5 sec/10 sec/60 sec ...)
Intervals for each device can vary.
Now I'm sending metric with **Set** using deviceId with tags that represent interval (5 sec, 10 sec, 30 sec, and more) but I'm not sure that it is correct.
What is the best way to realize it?

Answer (score 1):

Set is almost never the right custom metric type to use. It will send a count of the number of unique items per a given tag. The underlying items details will be stripped from the metric, meaning that from one time slice to the next, you will have no idea that actual true number of items over time.

For example

```
3:00:07-3:00:32 | 5 second bucket:[device1,device4,device7] -> 3 values
3:00:32-3:00:47 | 5 second bucket:[device1,device3] -> 2 values
```

Your time series to datadog will report `3`, and then `2`. But because the underlying device info is stripped you have no idea how to combine that 2 and 3 if you to zoom out in time and roll up the numbers to show 1 data point per minute. It could be any number from 3 to 5, but the Datadog backend has no idea. (even though we know that across those 30 seconds there were 4 unique values total)

Plus even if it was accurate somehow, you can't create an alert of it or notify anyone, because you won't know which device is having issues if you see a spike of devices in the 60 second bucket.

So let's go through other metric options.

---

The only metric types that are ever worth using are usually [distributions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/distributions/#overview) or [gauges](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/types/?tab=gauge#definition), or [counts].

A gauge metric is just a measurement of the latency at a point in time, it's usually good for things like CPU or Memory of a computer, or temperature in a room. Numbers that are impossible to actually collect all dat a points for so you just take measurements every 10 seconds, or every minute, or however often you never to get an idea of the behavior.

A count metric is more exact, it's the number of things that happened. Usually good for number of requests to a server, or number of files processed. Even something like the amount of bytes flowing through something, although that usually is treated like a gauge by most people.

Distributions are good for when you want to create a gauge metric, but you need detailed measurements for every single event that happens. For example a web server is handling hundreds of requests per second and we need to know the latency metrics of that server. It's not possible to send a latency metric for every request as a gauge. Gauges have a built in limit of 1 data point per second (in Datadog). Anything more sent in a 1 second interval gets dropped. But we need stats for every request, so a distribution will summarize the data, it keep a running count, min, max, average, and optionally several percentiles (p50, p75, p99).

---

I haven't seen many good use cases for metric types outside of those 3. For your scenario, it seems like you would want to be sending a distribution metric for that device interval. So device 1 sends a value of 10.14 and device 3 sends a value of 2.3 and so on.

Then you can use a [distribution widget](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/distribution/) in a dashboard to show the number of devices for each interval bucket.

Of course make sure you tag each metric by the device that is generating the metric.

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, I cannot afford to add the tag for each device because I have thousands of them and it would be very costly.

Comment: you said you already have deviceid so it's already tagged. You just need to change the function from set to distribution